# Maintaining application state in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to guess why, if I open my application, lock the device and some hours later resume the activity it crashes. I suppose thats why, after some time, Android destroy my app and then tries to resume and im not saving correctly the state of my activities.

How can I force Android to destroy my app as it does usually without having to wait hours?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Development tools:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

Note the feature "Immediately destroy activities". You should be able to use it in android emulators.

Answer (score 4):

You have both an onCreate() and onResume() method available to you as well as onPause() and onDestroy().  If you manage the life cycle properly with those methods (life cycle detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)) you should be able to eliminate the crash.

I'm guessing you do some setup in the onCreate() method that you should really be doing in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

If you `finish(`) your Activities and stop your services the process should be finished.

Of course is someone presses the menu button your activities will only be paused and not `finished()`'d  and when you come back their state may have been taken for other memory which you should check for when they come back.

Comment: The trick is knowing when to call finish().  If the app is being paused because the screen has been locked for a while, he could call finish in the onPause() method (I'm not sure what happens if you do... might onPause() get called again?), but it might be better to just use the rest of the lifecycle methods properly.

Comment: @Earl Earl is right, you should be able to check your state and handle it if is gone! :)

Comment: @inazaruk read the question correctly... which is how to debug a failure to use to use the lifecycle properly.

Comment: @inazaruk I think he was saying you read it correctly. :) I was wrong I give you both rep for pointing me in the right direction!